# UPS Rates API issue for multiple shipment dates

Tags: json, api, ups

I am using UPS Rates API ( JSON based with option Shoptimeintransit) to get available delivery dates for supplied shipment date.

https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_CA

In DeliveryTimeInformation, I am setting pickup info.

```
{
  "Security": {
    "UsernameToken": {
      "Username": "xxxxxxx",
      "Password": "xxxxxxx"
    },
    "UPSServiceAccessToken": {
      "AccessLicenseNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  "RateRequest": {
    "Request": {
      "RequestOption": "Shoptimeintransit",
      "TransactionReference": {
        "CustomerContext": "Your Customer Context"
      }
    },
    "CustomerClassification": {
      "Code": "00" 
    },
    "PickupType": {
      "Code": "06" 
    },
    "Shipment": {
      "DeliveryTimeInformation": {
        "PackageBillType": "07",
        "Pickup": {
          "Date": "20170925",
          "Time": "1140"
        }
      },
      "Shipper": {

        "ShipperNumber": "xxxxxxx",
        "Address": {
          "City": "Kansas City",
          "StateProvinceCode": "MO",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "xxxx"
        }
      },
      "ShipTo": {

        "Address": {
          "City": "Redwood",
          "StateProvinceCode": "CA",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "xxxx"
        }
      },
      "ShipFrom": {

        "Address": {
          "City": "Kansas City",
          "StateProvinceCode": "MO",
          "CountryCode": "US",
          "PostalCode": "xxxx"
        }
      },
      "Package": {
        "PackagingType": {
          "Code": "02" 
        },
        "Dimensions": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "IN" 
          },
          "Length": "5",
          "Width": "4",
          "Height": "3"
        },
        "PackageWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "LBS" 
          },
          "Weight": "1"
        }
      },

      "NumOfPieces": "3",
      "ShipmentRatingOptions": {
        "NegotiatedRatesIndicator": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Question is, I need available delivery dates for next N shipment dates, but API only takes single shipment date in DeliveryTimeInformation > Pickup section.

So, one possibility is to call API N times and combine results, which doesn't seems a good idea.

Anyone knows any related API that use to take pickup dates as list and return all possible delivery dates,service codes for supplied data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Docs state `Max Allowed: 1` for `DeliveryTimeInformation`, so no.

You can request it for the next API update (each January and July) through customer service, but you'll have to make `N` requests 'till then.

Comment: Thanks, Martin, I have done the same. I think they should offer some API for date range options.